# Accepting either a hash or an array of hashes as arguments to a Ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the method:

```
def self.store(params)
  params.each { }
end
```

It works perfectly, if I pass an Array of Hashes:

```
params = [ { key: 'value' }, { key: 'value' } ]
```

However, I might want to pass only a single Hash, instead of an Array of Hashes:

```
params = { key: 'value' }
```

**What would be the cleanest Ruby way to convert a Hash into an Array of Hashes?**

The Array() method a kind of ensures, that an array is always returned, but when the Hash is passed, it is converted into an Array itself.

```
Array({ key: 'value' }) => [[:key, 'value']]
```

What I need:

```
 { key: 'value' } => [ { key: 'value' } ]
```

Is there any nice way to implement this, or do I have to do a manual type checking with is_a?(Array) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, the best solution is to change the method to:

```
def self.store(*hashes)
  params = hashes.flatten
  puts params.inspect
end
```

- If you pass a single hash, it will be an array
- If you pass an array of hashes, it remains the same
- If you pases N hashes, it compacts all parameters into a one dimensional array.

You can pass whatever you want.

```
self.store({:key => 'value'}) # => [{:key => 'value'}]
self.store({:key => 'value'}, {:foo => 'bar'}) # => [{:key => 'value'}, {:foo => 'bar'}]
self.store([{:key => 'value'}, {:foo => 'bar'}]) # => [{:key => 'value'}, {:foo => 'bar'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
def self.store(params)
  params = [params].flatten
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
def self.store(params)
  (params.is_a?(Array) ? params : [params]).each {|single_hash| }
end
```